# I want to find out the total RAM size of AWS RDS through lambda python.I tried the code and got empty set.Is there any other way to find this?

Tags: list, aws-lambda

```
import json
import boto3,datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch',region_name=AWS_REGION)
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
    {
        'Id': 'memory',
        'MetricStat': {
        'Metric': {
                 'Namespace': 'AWS/RDS',
                 'MetricName': 'TotalMemory',
        'Dimensions': [
                {
                    "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
                    "Value": "mydb"  
                }]
         },
         'Period': 30,
         'Stat': 'Average',
          }
       }
         ],
     StartTime=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)).timestamp(),
     EndTime=datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
     )

     print(response)
```

The result is like below:

{'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'memory', 'Label': 'TotalMemory', 'Timestamps': [], 'Values': [], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the configured vCPU/Memory then it seems like we need to call `DescribeDBInstances` API to get `DBInstanceClass`, which contains the hardware information from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Summary)

You would need to use one of the CloudWatch metric names from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html#rds-metrics and it seems like we can retrieve the currently available memory metric using the `FreeableMemory`. I was able to get data (in bytes) as seen from the RDS' Monitoring console while using this metric name from your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the total amount of memory and other useful information associated with the RDS in the **CloudWatch console**.

**Step1:** Go to the CloudWatch console. Navigate to Log groups.

[image: Log groups]

---

**Step2:** Search for `RDSOSMetrics` in the search bar.

### [image: RDSOSMetrics]

**Step3:** Click on the log stream. You will be able to find all the details in the JSON. Your total memory would be present in the field titled `memory.total`. Sample result would be like this

```
{
    "engine": "MYSQL",
    "instanceID": "dbName",
    "uptime": "283 days, 21:08:36",
    "memory": {
        "writeback": 0,
        "free": 171696,
        "hugePagesTotal": 0,
        "inactive": 1652000,
        "pageTables": 19716,
        "dirty": 324,
        "active": 5850016,
        "total": 7877180,
        "buffers": 244312
    }   
}
```

---

I have intentionally reduced the message in the JSON because of the size, but there will be many other useful fields that you can find here.

You can use custom `jq` command-line utility to extract the field that you want from these log groups.

You can read more about this here [cloudwatch enhanced monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html).